# Program not entering an if-loop in Fortran even when condition is satisfied

Tags: if-statement, fortran, gfortran, fortran95, numerical-computing

This is the section of the code that is not running as expected. I had to include some old-style "pause" statements to pin-point the error location.

---

```
    iteration_index = 1
    y_refined = y_current + (0.5d0*dx*(dydx_predictor + dydx_refined_corrector))               ! Solution corresponds to i = 2, i.e., the refined Heun's method.

    relative_percent_error = 100.d0*(abs((y_refined - y_next)/y_refined))                         ! Calculation of relative percentage error. This is NOT true error.

    if (relative_percent_error > heun_percent_tolerance) then

        iteration_index = iteration_index + 1

        print*, 'first loop enter', x_next, relative_percent_error, iteration_index
        pause

        if (iteration_index < max_heun_number) then

            y_next = y_refined
            call dydx(x_next, y_next, dydx_refined_corrector)
            y_refined = y_current + (0.5d0*dx*(dydx_predictor + dydx_refined_corrector))
            relative_percent_error = 100.d0*(abs((y_refined - y_next)/y_refined))

            print*, 'second loop enter', x_next, relative_percent_error, iteration_index
            pause

        end if

    end if
```

---

Output is seen as follows:

```
first loop enter   1.0000000000000000        6.7763423346068707          2

PAUSE

To resume execution, type go.  Other input will terminate the job.

go

RESUMED

second loop enter   1.0000000000000000        1.6658644147581094        2

PAUSE 

To resume execution, type go.  Other input will terminate the job.

go

RESUMED

first loop enter   2.0000000000000000        6.6615482639252761         2

PAUSE 

To resume execution, type go.  Other input will terminate the job.
```

---

The values of `heun_percent_tolerance` is 0.01 and `max_heun_number` is 15. I expect the execution to enter the second if-loop for more iterations until the max limit of 15 is reached, but it seems that the code jumps to the next `x_next` value of 2.

I have even tried to combine the two conditions as `If (cond1 .and. cond2)`, that did not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is NO loop in your code! `IF` is not a loop! It will NOT be executed repeatedly unless you put there an actual loop.

If you want to loop some code while a condition is still valid, use a `DO WHILE` loop or a `DO` loop with `EXIT`.

```
do while (relative_percent_error > heun_percent_tolerance) 

    iteration_index = iteration_index + 1

    print*, 'first loop enter', x_next, relative_percent_error, iteration_index
    pause

    if (iteration_index < max_heun_number) then

        y_next = y_refined
        call dydx(x_next, y_next, dydx_refined_corrector)
        y_refined = y_current + (0.5d0*dx*(dydx_predictor + dydx_refined_corrector))
        relative_percent_error = 100.d0*(abs((y_refined - y_next)/y_refined))

        print*, 'second loop enter', x_next, relative_percent_error, iteration_index
        pause

    end if

end do
```

*Note the code is still likely incorrect*, you will have to restructure it, but the point is that you need an actual `DO` loop and not just an `IF` condition. An `IF` is not a loop.

Comment: Thank you @ Vladimir F. It worked and your inputs were correct.

Comment: FYI, I used a single "do while" statement and enforced both of the mathematical conditions using ".and." logical condition. I got what I wanted.